# Swiper Js on React not initializing on refresh but it does when document gets edited or saved

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swiper.js

As seen in the title, whenever I refresh the page slider doesn't initializing but when I edit or save the document it initializes.

Here is demo [**link**](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-sky-k1y7sj?file=/src/Cards.jsx)

When you first the link it should be seen broken, but if you type or save the document it will initialize work normally.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your `swiper` inside `useEffect` Hook

See example link: https://codesandbox.io/s/swiper-slider-r9hcym

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import Swiper from "swiper";
import CardItem from "./Card";
let imgs = [
  "https://healthjade.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/apple-fruit.jpg",
  "https://5.imimg.com/data5/VY/QT/MY-51857835/banana-fruit-500x500.jpg",
  "https://envato-shoebox-0.imgix.net/3de2/a6a4-c604-4b82-adae-332bfef74989/_M2_9019.jpg?auto=compress%2Cformat&fit=max&mark=https%3A%2F%2Felements-assets.envato.com%2Fstatic%2Fwatermark2.png&markalign=center%2Cmiddle&markalpha=18&w=700&s=54c7d180307a289c503e93a54a7987a5"
];

function Card() {

  useEffect(() => { // <-- Here
    const swiper = new Swiper(".swiper", {
      slidesPerView: 5,
      spaceBetween: 20,
      loop: true
    });

  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="swiper container mx-auto my-5 !pl-5 !pr-1 ">
      <div className="swiper-wrapper">
        <CardItem
          image={imgs[0]}
          rating={"2.5"}
          desc={"Life lessons with Katie Zaferes"}
          price={"130"}
          status={"Online"}
          count={"30"}
          country={"USA"}
        />
        <CardItem
          image={imgs[1]}
          rating={"3.6"}
          desc={"Learn wedding photography"}
          price={"160"}
          count={"6"}
          country={"UK"}
        />
        <CardItem
          image={imgs[2]}
          rating={"4.7"}
          desc={"Group Mountain Biking"}
          price={"180"}
          count={"12"}
          country={"CA"}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Card;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you explain what is useEffect(), and why we used here please?

Answer (score 0):

Just Import `import 'swiper/css'` and it will work like magic.